# How to run a jquery script on radio button check

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I'm am trying to run 2 comparison scripts when the radio button of each flight is clicked.

The //Compare airports part will compare whether the passenger will return to the same airport he departed from when clicking the equivalent booking radio button and show an alert in case he will be returning to a different airport.

And in the same way the //Compare Dates part will check whether his flight will arrive the next day and if yes show an alert stating just that.

I made a bare bones mockup of my code in codepen so you can have a clearer view of what i'm trying to do.

Thanks for taking the time to help!

http://codepen.io/JohnD/pen/myGZKP

```
//Compare airports
var a1 = $(".flight-1_1 > .departing-IATA").text();
var a2 = $(".flight-2_1 > .departing-IATA").text();

if (a1 != a2) {
      $('.da-alert').toggle();
};
//Compare dates 
var day1 = $(".flight-1_1 > .date").text();
var day2 = $(".flight-2_1 > .date").text();

if (day1 != day2) {
  $(".dd-alert").toggle();
}
```

Comment: I dont understand what your question is. On what question do you want a answer?

Comment: I need the scripts to run when the radio buttons for a flight are checked.

For example when .flight-1_1 's radio button is checked and .flight-2_1 's then it should pop an alert that the user will be landing in LGA when he returns from his flight and not JFK from which he departed 
(blue is departure flight and pink is return flight).

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to know way to run the code when radio button's are being chacked.

if you add new changed event to radio button, you will see the running code when the buttons are checked.

```
var airport1 = null
var airport2 = null
$('#radio_jfk_button').change(
    function() {
        airport1 = "jfk"
        if(airport1 != null && airport2 != null) {
            //compare
        }
    }
}
$('#radio_narita_button').change(
    function() {
        airport1 = "narita"
        if(airport1 != null && airport2 != null) {
            //compare
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I am trying to do, when each booking item's button is checked I need to run the scripts comparing the blue box's airport of arrival to the pink box's airport of departure. 
Unfortunately I'm not able to make your code work with mine.
Could you provide an example in a jsfiddle or codepen?

Comment: i'm making a code for you. but i understand you need some more system. because if' someone want flight  **11/04/2015 JFK to LHR** and **11/04/2015 LHR to LGA**, than he/she can't compare two.
because they are already checked. so i recommand you to think a batter system. i can write code, but i think my code will not help this problem

Comment: You are right. Can't I tell jQuery to run on an already checked flight? Thanks for trying to help!